# webRTC: Video stream plays on local but doesn't play on remote

Tags: webrtc, video-streaming, stun

#### Architectute

1. A webPage uses [RTCPeerConnection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/RTCPeerConnection) to create a connection. It uses a STUN and a TURN server in its configuration. It creates an offer and sends the Offer to the remote client only after all the candidates have been gathered

```
if(pc.iceGatheringState === "complete"){
            const resp = await fetch("REMOTE URL", {
                method: "post",
                body: JSON.stringify({
                    offer: btoa(JSON.stringify(pc.localDescription)),
                }),
            });
            const sdp = await resp.text();
            pc.setRemoteDescription(
                new RTCSessionDescription(JSON.parse(atob(sdp)))
            ).catch((e) => console.log(e));
        }
```

2. A remote (GO) server uses a REST API to accept the **offer** and respond with the **answer**. The answer is sent only after all the candidates have been gathered on the remote peer. I.e. after the `""` candidate has been received
3. The remote server has a local RTP stream which is being sent to the host. The host adds a transceiver before it sends the `offer`

```
pc.addTransceiver("video", { direction: "recvonly" });
```

4. When an `onTrack` event is received, the `stream` is added to a variable and ONLY set as `srcObject` of the `<video>` component when the `iceConnectionState` changes to `connected`

#### Issue

The above setup works perfectly in case of a local network. Both, the host and the peer chose a `host` candidate and the video plays perfectly.

When using a remote connection, both, in case of a STUN (srflx) candidate and a TURN(relay) candidate, the video does not play.

`chrome://webrtc-internals` clearly shows the the Transport has chosen the right candidates but there is no traffic on the `local` candidate chosen.

I can see using the UDP dump on the remote peer that the video stream is being sent perfectly.

#### Debug Info

1. On remote network, using a `srflex` candidate, the `nack` and `pli` counts are very high compared to a local network

```
For approx 15 sec of video

pliCount:
 local: 5
 remote: 221

nackCount:
 local: 7
 remote: 2577
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That sounds like packet loss to me. There are a few things that could be causing it.

Can you try lowering the bitrate of what you are sending? See if congestion is causing it.

Can you trying lowering the MTU? If you are forwarding packets from FFMPEG try appending pkt_size to the URL like [this](https://github.com/Sean-Der/goexamples/blob/webrtc/rpt-broadcast/publisher/ffmpeg.sh#L3)

Comment: Thanks. This works perfectly. what fixed it was the MTU size. I am curious about how did you arrive at 1280 as the MTU size. Is it 1200(webRTC) + headers?

Comment: When I was debugging a long time ago I stumbled on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47635545/why-webrtc-chose-rtp-max-packet-size-to-1200-bytes#comment82259843_47650260 and now 1280 is the first value I always go with :) 1200 is actually a better bet, that is the MTU that Pion goes with!